When navigating to a route the useFetch won't work reactive
I am trying to use useFetch in my page component, so when I navigate to this page using nuxt-link the useFetch will send the request and get the response of 200, but the items fetched from the api won't be shown in the DOM, but if I reload the page everything is working right.
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <BreadCrumb />
    <h1 class="title">{{ brand }}</h1>
    <div class="models-container">
      <Model
        v-for="model in models"
        :name="model.model"
        :image="model.image"
        @click="handleClick(model.model)"
      />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup>
import axios from "axios";
import issue from "~/utils/Encrypt.util";

const router = useRouter();
const { brand } = useRoute().params;

const models = ref([]);

const authToken = useCookie("Authorization-Token");

if (authToken.value) {
  const { data: tempModels } = useFetch(
    `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL}/v1/vehicles/search`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        filters: [
          {
            column_name: "manufacture",
            operand: "IsEqualTo",
            value: brand,
          },
          {
            column_name: "is_deleted",
            operand: "IsEqualTo",
            value: 0,
          },
        ],
      },
      headers: {
        "Client-Token": import.meta.env.VITE_API_CLIENT_TOKEN,
        "Authorization-Token": authToken.value,
      },
    }
  );
  models.value = tempModels.value?.value.vehicles;
}

onMounted(() => {
  if (!authToken.value) {
    issue().then((token) => {
      authToken.value = token["Authorization-Token"];

      axios
        .post(
          `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL}/v1/vehicles/search`,
          {
            filters: [
              {
                column_name: "manufacture",
                operand: "IsEqualTo",
                value: brand,
              },
              {
                column_name: "is_deleted",
                operand: "IsEqualTo",
                value: 0,
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            headers: {
              "Client-Token": import.meta.env.VITE_API_CLIENT_TOKEN,
              "Authorization-Token": authToken.value,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          models.value = res.data.value.vehicles;
        });
    });
  }
});

function handleClick(model) {
  router.push(`/vehicles/${brand}/${model}`);
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.models-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>


I am trying to save some data in the cookies and if the user has no Authorization-Token, one will be made for him and will be set in the cookies and I can use it in my request.
I'm new to SSR and I don't know how can I handle sending the token with my requests and also I don't know how reactive variables made with ref will work in SSR applications.
I tried changing the <nuxt-link> tag to <a> tags or navigation using useRouter but it has no difference.

Check your Vue devtools to see where is the issue. Is it properly populated in your state?

@kissu Yes, I checked it and I can see that the data is there, and when I click the refresh button in the devtools the data will be shown.

By the way, I replaced the useFetch with the combination of useAsyncData and $fetch.
if (authToken.value) {
  await useAsyncData(async () => {
try {
  const response = await $fetch(
    ...
 )
} catch {

.
